# Fastest way of converting integer to string in java

Tags: java, performance, optimization, benchmarking

Everytime I had to convert an `int`into a `String` I picked either `""+a`or `Integer.toString(a)`. Now I wondered which way is faster, so I wrote a simple benchmark that calls function_1, function_2 and function_3 10000000 times and prints how long it takes to process the functions. Here are the functions:

```
public static String i="";
public static String j="";
public static String k="";

public static void function_1()
{
    i=Integer.toString(getOne());
}

public static void function_2()
{
    j=""+1;
}

public static void function_3()
{
    j=""+getOne();
}

public static int getOne()
{
    return 1;
}
```

the output is:

```
Benchmarking starting...
Executing function_1 10000000 time(s)...
Done executing function_1 in 476 ms.
Executing function_2 10000000 time(s)...
Done executing function_2 in 8 ms.
Executing function_3 10000000 time(s)...
Done executing function_3 in 634 ms.
Benchmarking complete!
```

I think function_2 is so fast, because it is compiled as

```
public static void function_2()
{
    j="1";
}
```

so to avoid that, I used the function `getOne()` instead. But here is the interesting part(for me): `function_3` must be compiled without using the original `toString` method of `Object`(in this case `Integer.toString(1)` because `int` is primitive). My question is: How does the compiler actually threat `""+1` so it is slower then calling `Integer.toString(1)`?

Comment: Have you considered looking at the bytecode? Also, micro-benchmarks are, in general, useless. Things could be happening at the JIT level as well.

Comment: `""+1` is the *fastest* (by a lot) according to those numbers. And, it only seems intuitive that a specialized function is [slightly] faster than calling a function and performing a string-wise concatenating the result ..

Comment: If you look at the bytecode you'll probably find that `function_3` uses a `StringBuilder` while `function_1` doesn't. And internally, the `StringBuilder` will call `String.valueOf()`.

Comment: @pst yes, but this isn't the question. The question is why function_3 is faster then function_1.

Comment: @D180 Among other things: 'How does the compiler actually threat ""+1 so it is slower the calling Integer.toString(1)?' Write the question consistently/accurately.

Comment: @D180 - according to your numbers, `function_3` is *slower* than `function_1`. If you're wondering why it's "faster," stop wondering :-)

Comment: @DaveNewton what tool can be used to look at the bytecode?

Comment: @D180 - `javap -c MyClass`

Comment: The fastest way to convert an integer to a string is probably to use Integer.toString(int).  (Though a clever programmer could probably do considerably better.)

Comment: @qualebs - Just do the conversion yourself -- repeated divide/modulo by 10, and add in '0' (the character value).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`""` and `1` are known at compile time. This is why in `function_2` `"" + 1` is really replaced by `"1"` while convertion to bytecode.

`getOne()` result is unknown at the compilation time so the concatenation will be done in runtime. BUT because concatenation (+) is not efficient it is likely that compiler will change this to `StringBuilder.append()` based implementation.

Don't believe me? Try: `javap -c ClassName.class` and you will see something like this:

```
public static void function_2();
Code:
   0: ldc           #39                 // String 1
   2: putstatic     #16                 // Field j:Ljava/lang/String;
   5: return        


public static void function_3();
Code:
   0: new           #42                 // class java/lang/StringBuilder
   3: dup           
   4: invokespecial #44                 // Method java/lang/StringBuilder."<init>":()V
   7: invokestatic  #28                 // Method getOne:()I
  10: invokevirtual #45                 // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(I)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
  13: invokevirtual #49                 // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.toString:()Ljava/lang/String;
  16: putstatic     #16                 // Field j:Ljava/lang/String;
  19: return
```

`function_2()` have only one String "1", while function_3 have all these method calls with additional StringBuilder inside :)

Keep in mind that some optimization may occur at runtime, but this behavior is JVM and it's configuration dependent.

Answer (score 1):

I tested the following functions on 10,000,000 iterations:

```
public static void no_func_maybe_constant()
{
    j= "" + 1;
}

public static void no_func_no_constant()
{
    j = "";
    j = j + 1;
}

public static void yes_func_maybe_constant()
{
    j = "" + getOne();
}

public static void yes_func_no_constant()
{
    j = "";
    j = j + getOne();
}
```

My results:

```
no_func_maybe_constant Took 0.028058674s
no_func_no_constant Took 1.449465242s
yes_func_maybe_constant Took 1.275561897s
yes_func_no_constant Took 1.263362257s
```

The difference between not calling the function and calling the function was indeed negligible, so it seems in the case of `"" + 1` it was indeed doing some compile-time constant calculation. Interesting that without a function it sometimes took less time...

Comment: so calling a function takes so much time?

Comment: @D180: Yea, it takes way longer to call a function than to simply have a constant already there.

Comment: @Claudiu why doesn't the compiler in-line `function_3`?

Comment: @D180 Nah. I think your guess in your question is correct. It's being optimized to "1". So no conversion is actually needed. The conversion would probably be much more expensive than the function call.

Comment: @Tushar: maybe it does, maybe not. maybe try `j = ""; j = j + 1;` as an additional test to try to trick the compiler into not doing compile-time constant evaluation, if that's what it is doing. as Dave said in the comment, the only way to check is by looking at the bytecode

Comment: @Tushar: if it were inlining then the only difference would be doing the conversion at compile-time or not. if it's not inlining then the difference would be between doing the function call or not.

Comment: I just tested two functions one billion times, the first function is empty and the second calls another empty function. The difference is minimal, so it clearly isn't the function call that takes that much time.

Comment: i got curios so am running some tests, will see what happens

Comment: @D180  The compiler can optimize away empty functions as no-ops. In general setting up micro-benchmarks in the dynamically-compiled environment of the JVM is very complicated and it's not easy to correctly guess what the compiler is actually doing under the hood. http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-benchmark1/index.html

Answer (score 0):

The difference between 2 and 3 is likely due to having to call a method to get the integer. When you call a method, it creates a new activation record which complicates the call stack so there is more going on here unless the JVM's JIT is capable of inlining that static function call to just the single return value (almost certainly not happening here).

Comment: I would expect the JITC to inline that call.  Quite possibly the JITC is not being activated for some reason (which makes the whole exercise bogus, since the interpreter overhead swamps everything else).