# how to understand whether a new String object has been created

Tags: java, string, oop

I am confused by the answers and the results i am getting on compiling a 3 line program. Here is the code along with its opcodes: http://pastebin.com/B1xxAjcp If i am not totally wrong, its evident that

```
String s="abcd";
String s1=new String("efgh");
s.concat("ijkl");
```

these lines corresponds to these opcodes:

```
1: istore_1
        2: ldc           #2                  // String abcd
        4: astore_2
        5: new           #3                  // class java/lang/String
        8: dup
        9: ldc           #4                  // String efgh
       11: invokespecial #5                  // Method java/lang/String."<init>
":(Ljava/lang/String;)V
       14: astore_3
       15: aload_2
       16: ldc           #6                  // String ijkl
       18: invokevirtual #7                  // Method java/lang/String.concat:
(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
```

So to my understanding `ldc #index` means that instead of creating a new object, creates a reference to the constant literal pool , and pushes it to stack.

A new object is created, `new` and `dup` commands occur before the `ldc #index`. But in this question [How many String object..?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15760661/how-many-string-object) , the second answer says that `ldc #index` implies that String object has been created,The explanation goes like this:

```
public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: ldc           #2                  // String ObjectOneObjectTwo
       2: astore_1
       3: getstatic     #3                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
       6: aload_1
       7: invokevirtual #4                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
      10: return
}
```

`As you see, there is only one String object, which contains "ObjectOneObjectTwo".`

- I cannot understand (nor are the people helping me) where did i get the concept wrong?
- Does `ldc #index` means a object is created and linked with a reference from the pool, but it does-not imply that a "new" object has been created?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
String s="abcd";
```

String from literal "abcd" is created in String pool.

```
String s1=new String("efgh");
```

String from literal "efgh" is created in String pool. 
New non-interned String created, contents of String in pool copied to it

```
s.concat("ijkl");
```

String from literal "ijkl" is created in string pool.
New non-interned String created, contents of two interned Strings copied into it.

This created 3 instances of `String` in the pool, and 2 non-interned (not in the pool) instances of `String`.

**Edit to add:** The `lcd` bytecode op is pushing the reference (value) of a `String` in the pool onto the stack.

Comment: Erm, last time I looked, 3 + 2 = **5** :)

Comment: 6 with the `String` created with `concat`, no ? ^^

Comment: OK, my bad. I've read too fast. That was your second non-interned String

Comment: so if lcd doesnot imply object creations , how do i understand how many of those objects are created? you did clarify in this case, but in other cases... @BrianRoach .

Comment: @shortCircuit Each .class file has a constants_pool. The compiler stores literals in this section at compile time. `lcd` is loading from the constants_pool - the `#x` that follows it is the index it's loading from.

Comment: Trying to find good references for you; Charter 5 of the JVMS is specifically what talks about it - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-5.html - chapter 4 gives the .class file layout http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html

Comment: To be clear: you *don't* know how many String objects are being created in the pool once you get outside these simple examples. If N different .class files containing the same String literal get loaded by the classloader, then ... one String is created in the pool.

Answer (score 2):

In the first line, a new string "abcd" is created in the string pool. String object "s" is given a reference to this string. In the second line, another string "efgh" is created in string pool and a new object of type String "s1" is created, and it is given reference to the new string created in the pool. In the third line, another string "ijkl" is created in the string pool, after the concat() operation, another new string "abcdijkl" is created and now String object "s" refers to this newly created string. So, 3 objects in the string pool, and 2 on the heap.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the real thing here is this:

```
 String s1=new String("efgh"); //this will create TWO objects : one in the pool and one in the heap.
```

Comment: i understand that, my main problem is with the first and last lines. if new objects were created due to those statements. Mr. @Brian provided the answer.